# Keep header in messages.pot using Flask-Babel pybabel extract

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

Is it possible to keep/set the header in the messages.pot, between execution? I found three options to control the header. But there is more info I would like to keep/set, like project name/version etc.

```
--msgid-bugs-address
--copyright-holder
--omit-header
```

Now everytime I execute `pybabel extract` I get back the default header. I don't realy use the header, but if it's there, I would like it to be correct.

I guess this is is a standard header used by gettext, and maybe pybabel doesn't support it to the max. Am I correct?

Btw I'm using Flask-Babel if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Now I get it. You are not supposed to edit the messages.pot file. It's only the header in the messages.po files that you should change. That header is unmodified (except for datetime) between each execution of `pybabel update`.